# What to use i.e Message Filter or Header Value router while propagating messages based on a header value?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

In our spring integration project we have to propagate message further down the flow only if we received a success value from a third party api.

Currently i am setting the header value to

> success

or

> fail

based on whether we received the expected response or not and then routing the message to success or failure channel respectively.

***I can also achieve the same flow by using a message filter but was wondering if that would be the correct approach?***

***httpInboundAdapter->initiateChannel->messageProcessor (Service activator)-> filterChannel->headerValueRouter->responseChannel->response***

Below is the integration graph for the same:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's completely your choice; a filter with a discard channel is functionally equivalent to a binary router.